# Only white noise in PyAudio blocking stream..?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm doing *almost* everything exactly as the pyaudio documentation describes. The main difference: in the stream loop, I am running my song data through a filter that outputs audio data as an array. The resulting output is only white noise. Here's my code:

```
import librosa as lr
y, sr = lr.load(song_filename)

# open stream
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

while _: 
    x = my_filter(parameter, y=y[CHUNK])
    stream.write(x)
    CHUNK = updateCHUNK()
```

My guess is that librosa uses numpy array while pyaudio uses bytes. So I tried this:

```
while _: 
    x = my_filter(parameter, y=y[CHUNK])
    x = x.tobytes()
    stream.write(x)
    CHUNK = updateCHUNK()
```

Nothing was fixed by .tobytes(). Can anyone suggest solutions to this issue?

**Edit:**
I realize that I'm not ready to look for solutions. Still trying to understand what the **problem** is.

Comment: In other words, is data type my issue? If it is, how can I change the type. If data type is not the issue, what might it be?

Comment: Could it be a transformation problem? Where the array is indeed transformed into bytes object, but is not transformed to the right shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use sounddevice instead of PyAdudio. PyAudio seems like a broken library when it comes to audio recording.

A simple line to record audio from sounddevice would be something like this:

```
import sounddevice as sd

audio = sd.rec(capture_frames, samplerate=sample_rate, channels=channels, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then you can write to a wav file using the soundfile library:

```
import soundfile as sf

sf.write('captured_audio.wav', audio, sample_rate)
```